# Linking Table Cells to Checkboxes Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, onclick

I have a set of checkboxes for months and I also have a table containing cells for each month. The 'data-val' attribute of the cells is the same as the 'id' of the checkboxes. I want to add a onClick to the table cells so that when a cell is clicked, the checkbox that has the same 'id' as the cells 'data-val', should be checked so long as the table cell is checked.

So far, I've managed to register an onClick to the table cells. However, all the checkboxes are checked when a single cell is clicked rather than the corresponding checkbox. How can I solve this?

```
        function MonthCalCheck() {

        const checkboxMonthElement = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxMonth');
        var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#Month_Table td');

        cells.forEach(f => f.addEventListener('click', event => {

            for (var x = 0; x < checkboxMonthElement.length; x++) {

                if (cells[x].getAttribute('data-val') == checkboxMonthElement[x].getAttribute('id')) {

                    checkboxMonthElement[x].checked = true;
                }   
            }
        }));


    }

    MonthCalCheck();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `forEach` and instead of using the variable `f` as the current element in the iteration, you're using `cells[x]` which is indeed equal to `checkboxMonthElement[x]` when comparing their data values.

Replace `cells[x]` with `f`.

Comment: I get the error: Add:671 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.f.addEventListener.event when I change cells[x] to cells[f]

Comment: You should replace `cells[x]` with `f` as follow `f.getAttribute('data-val') == checkboxMonthElement[x].getAttribute('id')`. **NOT** `x` with `f`.

Comment: Can't believe I made that mistake. Many thanks for the help!